# How do I use a different color for different border edges of a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

In order to draw a border around my UIView, I use the following code :

```
[_rectView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[_rectView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
```

For one view, I would like to render only the right edge of my layer in black, the other 3 edges should be transparent.

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CALayer's delegate to draw anything, including a black line on the right edge. I have had success with custom layer drawing in [-drawLayer:inContext:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).